# Line breaking within ```\left[...\right]```

Tags: align, line-breaking

I want to break the line which is within `\left[...\right]`.

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
            \frac{\partial U}{\partial k} &=x^k\log x
            \left[1-\frac{1}{(k+2)^2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{(k+2)^2(k+4)^2}x^{4}-\frac{1}{(k+2)^2(k+4)^2(k+6)^2}x^6+....\right]+x^k\\
            & \left[\frac{2}{(k+2)^3}x^{2}+\frac{1}{(k+2)^2(k+4)^2}\left\{-\frac{2}{k+2}-\frac{2}{k+4}\right\}x^{4}
            -\frac{1}{(k+2)^2(k+4)^2(k+6)^2}\left\{-\frac{2}{k+2}\right.\\
            &\left.-\frac{2}{k+4}-\frac{2}{k+6}\right\}x^6+....\right]
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did I truncate correctly according to your question?

Comment: you can not use left/right, use fixed sizes such as Bigl, unrelated but are you really using `\usepackage{epsf}` ??? latex has had standard graphics inclusion for 30 years, why use that 1980s non stadard package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle eps or ps reminds me of bad times when I had to set up bounding boxes. Stories to forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
            \frac{\partial U}{\partial k} &=x^k\log x
            \Biggl[1-\frac{1}{(k+2)^2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{(k+2)^2(k+4)^2}x^{4}-\frac{1}{(k+2)^2(k+4)^2(k+6)^2}x^6+\dotsb\Biggr]+x^k\\
            & \Biggl[\frac{2}{(k+2)^3}x^{2}+\frac{1}{(k+2)^2(k+4)^2}\left\{-\frac{2}{k+2}-\frac{2}{k+4}\right\}x^{4}\\
            &-\frac{1}{(k+2)^2(k+4)^2(k+6)^2}\left\{-\frac{2}{k+2}-\frac{2}{k+4}-\frac{2}{k+6}\right\}x^6+\dotsb\Biggr]
            \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you can brief what changes have you done? Not related, but ```=``` is unsolicited there

Comment: @ManjoyDas 1) I have included the geometry package to have symmetrical edges; 2) I have used \Biggl[ and \Biggr] everywhere because the commands \Biggl[ and \Biggr] allow two equations placed in the align environment to be broken without error.

Comment: +1, and belated happy new year! One minor quibble: I'd use `\dots` (short for "dots-binary", I suppose) instead of `\ldots`. Oh, and don't load the `epsf` package, please. :-) Load `graphixc` instead.

Comment: @Mico Oh my dear friend. A BIGG happy new year for you and your family. I have done the changhed that you have ask to me.

Comment: Oops, just noticed I had a typo in my earlier comment -- I meant to write `\dotsb`, not `\dots`. My bad!

Comment: just a little query! What should I use to break inside```\left\{...\right\}```?

Comment: @ManjoyDas \Bigl\{ and \Bigr\}

Comment: Thanks everyone!! Happy new year..